# PHP & MongoDB show results grouped by date

Tags: php, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have an mongodb collection with following documents:

```
{
  "_id" : ObjectId("547af6aea3f0eba7148b4567"),
  "check_id" : "f5d654e7-257d-4a93-ae50-2d59dfeeb451",
  "chunks" : NumberLong(200),
  "num_hosts" : NumberLong(1000),
  "num_rbls" : NumberLong(163),
  "owner" : NumberLong(7901),
  "created" : ISODate("2014-11-30T10:51:26.924Z"),
  "started" : ISODate("2014-11-30T10:51:31.558Z"),
  "finished" : ISODate("2014-11-30T10:57:08.512Z")
}

{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54db19a858a5d395a18b4567"),
  "check_id" : "9660e510-1349-43f3-9d5e-8bf4b06179be",
  "chunks" : NumberLong(2),
  "num_hosts" : NumberLong(10),
  "num_rbls" : NumberLong(166),
  "owner" : NumberLong(7901),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-02-11T08:58:17.118Z"),
  "started" : ISODate("2015-02-11T08:58:18.78Z"),
  "finished" : ISODate("2015-02-11T08:58:47.486Z")
}


{
  "_id" : ObjectId("54db267758a5d30eab8b4567"),
  "check_id" : "9660e510-1349-43f3-9d5e-8bf4b06179be",
  "chunks" : NumberLong(2),
  "num_hosts" : NumberLong(10),
  "num_rbls" : NumberLong(166),
  "owner" : NumberLong(7901),
  "created" : ISODate("2015-02-11T09:52:55.388Z"),
  "started" : ISODate("2015-02-11T09:52:56.109Z"),
  "finished" : ISODate("2015-02-11T09:53:22.095Z")
}
```

What I need is to get the result and produce an array similar to this:

```
Array
(
    [2015-02-11] => array
        (
            //array with results from 2015-02-11
        )
    [2014-11-30] => array
        (
            //array with results from 2014-11-30
        )
)
```

I know that it's possible to just perform simply collection->find and then loop through results and use php logic to achieve my goal but is it possible to make it using mongo? Maybe using aggregation framework?

**EDIT: I want to group results by "created" date**

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Which date you want to group like group by  `created, started or finished` ?

Comment: @yogesh thanks! I want to group it by created date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to solve this using the aggregation framework. Here is the answer, in case anyone need it.

```
$op = array(
    array(
        '$project' => array(
            'data' => array(
                'check_id' => '$check_id',
                'chunks' => '$chunks',
                'num_hosts' => '$num_hosts',
                'num_rbls' => '$num_rbls',
                'owner' => '$owner',
                'started' => '$started',
                'finished' => '$finished',
            ),
            'year' => array('$year' => '$created' ),
            'month' => array('$month' => '$created' ),
            'day' => array('$dayOfMonth' => '$created'),
        )
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array('year' => '$year', 'month' => '$month', 'day' => '$day'),
            'reports_data' => array('$push' => '$data'),
        )
    ),
);

$c = $collection->aggregate($op);
```

Answer (score 2):

Monogo aggregation [mongo aggregation](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.mongodb.org%2Fmanual%2Faggregation&ei=ZUvbVO7nL8myoQSb24GoBA&usg=AFQjCNHCfJjoJmeYzFwKcVwfqp7ItADVdw&bvm=bv.85761416,d.cGU) `group` used for this, so below query may solve your problem

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$created",
    "data": {
        "$push": {
            "check_id": "$check_id",
            "chunks": "$chunks",
            "num_hosts": "$num_hosts",
            "num_rbls": "$num_rbls",
            "owner": "$owner",
            "started": "$started",
            "finished": "$finished"
        }
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Or

```
db.collectionName.aggregate({
    "$group": {
    "_id": "$created",
    "data": {
        "$push": "$$ROOT"
    }
    }
}).pretty()
```

Also in mongo 2.8 [$dateToString](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/dateToString/) provide facility to convert ISO date to string format so below query also work

```
db.collectionName.aggregate([
    {
    "$project": {
        "yearMonthDay": {
            "$dateToString": {
                "format": "%Y-%m-%d",
                "date": "$created"
            }
        },
        "check_id": "$check_id",
        "chunks": "$chunks",
        "num_hosts": "$num_hosts",
        "num_rbls": "$num_rbls",
        "owner": "$owner",
        "started": "$started",
        "finished": "$finished"
    }
    },
    {
    "$group": {
        "_id": "$yearMonthDay",
        "data": {
            "$push": "$$ROOT"
        }
    }
    }
]).pretty()
```

Comment: @МиленМихалев I think instead of `collectionName`  you should write your collection name .

Comment: of course. I have changed it to my collection name.

Comment: Ok ok is shows any error? But, I don't know same documents above shows me results

Comment: @МиленМихалев Hi I found another way I think this will also helpful to you .